# TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. After NPM install

Tags: node.js, typescript, requirejs

I've searched stack overflow for this issue, but am still unclear on why this is happening/how to fix.

I wanted Node Typings in my Typescript project so I entered this command:

```
npm install @types/node --save
```

Which resulted in:

```
c:/xyz/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(89,13)
error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.
Variable 'require' must be of type 'Require', but here has type 'NodeRequire'.
```

My machine had node version 7.0.3
The installed types was for version + @types/node@7.0.28

If I remove uninstall the typings my project compiles with no problems.

It appears as if the typings content is not correct per the error message! Fixing it is messy.  Any tips?

Here's the failing line of code in index.d.ts[image: NodeRequire]

Seems like the NodeRequire (interfaces) need to be bypassed in favor of Require.js?

This is the TSConfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "OfficeFabric/*": [
                "node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/lib-amd/*"
            ]
        }
    } 
}
```

I tried the Exclude suggestion below which didn't work.  Github says, if module resolution is NODE then exclude won't work anyway.

Comment: Have you tried adding `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` to your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: The tsconfig.json already has the "exclude": ["node_modules"] line but i have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally found the root cause:  Node's index.d.ts file was conflicting with Require's index.d.ts file both were declaring a variable named require.  The way I found it was to rename ***require*** to ***nrequire*** then search the project for all instances of **nrequire**.  There are many solutions,

1. Rename the variable (will get wiped out on npm install or update).
2. In TypeScript use the --types option to use one or the other but not both.
3. Just remove the node typing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue many times in my project at work, I solved it by uninstalling the existing `node_modules` and installing a newer version of the existing `node_modules`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue many times in my project at work.
I solved it with a change in the typings.d.ts` file:

```js
declare var require: any;
```